# Combine columns in matrix having same column name

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a matrix with columns that duplicate character column names.

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(1:10,12,replace=TRUE), nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE,
       dimnames = list(c("s1", "s2", "s3"),c("x", "y","x","y")))

m
   x y  x  y
s1 3 4  6 10
s2 3 9 10  7
s3 7 1  3  2
```

I need to sum all columns with the same column name into only one column i.e.

```
m <- matrix(c(9,14,13,16,10,3), nrow = 3, ncol = , byrow = TRUE,dimnames = list(c("s1", "s2", "s3"),c("x", "y")))

    x  y
s1  9 14
s2 13 16
s3 10  3
```

I have had a play with the simple sum in the aggregate function but haven't had any luck. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Advice #1: provide a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can interpret your question in any number of ways. This makes it impossible to understand. Please post sample data and expected results.

Comment: OK, now I have your sample data.  This is a good start.  What is the expected results?

Comment: I just added the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to make one more edit. Since you use `sample` you introduce randomness into the sample data.  This makes it not reproducible.  To fix this, you need to add `set.seed(1)` or similar before the first sample. I've added this, to get you started.  You'll need to updated the expected results with this specific set of data.

Comment: PS, also add in words what the aggregation function is.  Simple sum?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example (EDIT: as Joshua already pointed out! :p)

Comment: Your expected results don't seem to match any reasonable function for combining columns of `m`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien That's because the input data is random. I edited the question to add the seed, but clearly any operation on random data will resemble randomness... Hopefully the OP will fix this in a few minutes. She seems pretty responsive.

Comment: just fixed it so it matches. I just need to combine the columns that have the same names i.e. x and y

Comment: You mean you have to *sum*. Combine can mean anything.  Please be specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this solution won't win any awards for transparency of code, but I rather like it:

```
nms <- colnames(m)
m %*% sapply(unique(nms),"==", nms)
#     x  y
# s1  9 14
# s2 13 16
# s3 10  3
```

---

It works by constructing a matrix that forms appropriate linear combinations of `m`'s columns. To see how it works, pick apart the second line into its two component matrices, which are multiplied together using `%*%`, like this:

```
 -          -      -   -
|  3 4  6 10 |    | 1 0 |
|  3 9 10  7 |    | 0 1 |
|  7 1  3  2 |    | 1 0 |
 -          -     | 0 1 |
                   -   -
```

Comment: +1 Because after all my work to figure out what the OP wanted, you still managed to steal it :-) Plus, I have no idea what you did!

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly but I don't exactly understand why at the moment but will pick it apart in time.

Comment: @Elizabeth -- I just added a bit of explanation. There are a bunch of R tricks in that short line of code; it may not be clear but (for the same reason) it'll probably reward whatever attention you give it.

Comment: Awesome - I just got this working for sparse Matrix object too, using a sparse logical matrix times a dgCMatrix.

Answer (score 7):

```
nms <- colnames(m)
sapply(unique(nms), function(i)rowSums(m[, nms==i]))

   x  y
s1  9 14
s2 13 16
s3 10  3
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me clarify the question and also for your answer!

Comment: +1 I do feel like a thief, and would've fessed up earlier if I hadn't been behind some kind of firewall that was treating me like a robot, and not letting me make any comments at all. Still shocked that I got the accept with my odd little line of code!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I'm afraid you fail the Turing test. Only a robot will dream up such an obfuscated answer, and then make up such an unlikely excuse.