# How to combine columns with identical names in a large sparse Matrix

Tags: r, performance, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse dgTMatrix from the **Matrix** package, that has picked up some duplicate `colnames`.  I want to combine these by summing the columns with the same names, forming a reduced Matrix.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512441/combine-columns-in-matrix-having-same-column-name), which I adapted for sparse matrix operations.  But: It's still very slow on large objects.  I am wondering if someone has a better solution that operates directly on the indexed elements of the sparse matrix that would be faster.  For instance, `A@j` indexes (from zero) the labels in `A@Dimnames[[2]]`, which could be compacted and used to reindex `A@j`.  (Note: This is why I used the triplet sparse matrix form rather than the **Matrix** default of column-sparse matrixes since figuring out that `p` value makes my head hurt every time.)

```
require(Matrix)

# set up a (triplet) sparseMatrix
A <- sparseMatrix(i = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), j = 1:6, x = rep(1:3, 2), 
                  giveCsparse = FALSE,
                  dimnames = list(paste0("r", 1:2), rep(letters[1:3], 2)))
A
## 2 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
##    a b c a b c
## r1 1 . 3 . 2 .
## r2 . 2 . 1 . 3

str(A)
## Formal class 'dgTMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
##   ..@ i       : int [1:6] 0 1 0 1 0 1
##   ..@ j       : int [1:6] 0 1 2 3 4 5
##   ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 2 6
##   ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
##   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "r1" "r2"
##   .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "a" "b" "c" "a" ...
##   ..@ x       : num [1:6] 1 2 3 1 2 3
##   ..@ factors : list()

# my matrix-based attempt
OP1 <- function(x) {
    nms <- colnames(x)
    if (any(duplicated(nms))) 
        x <- x %*% Matrix(sapply(unique(nms),"==", nms))
    x
} 
OP1(A)
## 2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##    a b c
## r1 1 2 3
## r2 1 2 3
```

It worked fine, but seems quite slow on the huge sparse objects on which I intend to use it.  Here's a larger item:

```
# now something bigger, for testing
set.seed(10)
nr <- 10000     # rows
nc <- 26*100    # columns - 100 repetitions of a-z
nonZeroN <- round(nr * nc / 3)  # two-thirds sparse
B <- sparseMatrix(i = sample(1:nr, size = nonZeroN, replace = TRUE), 
                  j = sample(1:nc, size = nonZeroN, replace = TRUE),
                  x = round(runif(nonZeroN)*5+1),
                  giveCsparse = FALSE, 
                  dimnames =  list(paste0("r", 1:nr), rep(letters, nc/26)))
print(B[1:5, 1:10], col.names = TRUE)
## 5 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
##     a b c  d e f g h i  j
## r1  . . 5  . . 2 . . .  .
## r2  . . .  . . . . . .  4
## r4  . . .  . . . . 3 3  .
## r3  2 2 .  3 . . . 3 .  .
## r5  3 . .  1 . . . . .  5

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OPmatrixCombine1 = OP1(B), times = 30)
## Unit: milliseconds
##             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
## OPmatrixCombine1 578.9222 619.3912 665.6301 631.4219 646.2716 1013.777    30
```

Is there a better way, where better means *faster* and, if possible, not requiring the construction of additional large objects?

Comment: Not faster (at least for only a few unique "colnames") and, also, same as yours: `B %*% sparseMatrix(i = seq_len(ncol(B)), j = match(colnames(B), unique(colnames(B))), x = 1L)` avoids creating the `sapply(unique(colnames(B)), "==", colnames(B))` "matrix" which is then passed to "Matrix" to become sparse.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt using the index reindexing I had in mind, which I figured out with a friend's help ([Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6233565/patrick-perry) is that you?).  It reindexes the `j` values, and uses the very handy feature of `sparseMatrix()` that adds the `x` values together for elements whose index positions are the same.

```
OP2 <- function(x) {
    nms <- colnames(x)
    uniquenms <- unique(nms)
    # build the sparseMatrix again: x's with same index values are automatically
    # added together, keeping in mind that indexes stored from 0 but built from 1
    sparseMatrix(i = x@i + 1, 
                 j = match(nms, uniquenms)[x@j + 1],
                 x = x@x,
                 dimnames = list(rownames(x), uniquenms),
                 giveCsparse = FALSE)
}
```

Results are the same:

```
OP2(A)
## 2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##    a b c
## r1 1 2 3
## r2 1 2 3

all.equal(as(OP1(B), "dgTMatrix"), OP2(B))
## [1] TRUE
```

But faster:

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OPmatrixCombine1 = OP1(B), 
               OPreindexSparse = OP2(B),
               times = 30)
## Unit: relative
##              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  OPmatrixCombine1 1.756769 1.307651 1.360487 1.341814 1.346864 1.460626    30
##   OPreindexSparse 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    30
```

Comment: the tabulation for overlapping indices is very handy indeed; with more than `length(letters)` unique values, the `match(x, unique(x))` approach will be a lot faster than the `length(unique(x)) * length(x)` loop in the `sapply` of your first approach.